# Is it safe to use a MySQL database for recording positions on a multiplayer game?

Tags: php, sql, flash, actionscript

Would it be safe to use a MySQL database to record positions of players on the screen?

Then everyone second, Flash retrieves the new position data in the database and sets the players' positions of the map to the new positions?

I'm not sure how slow this would be.

I know PHP.
I know SQL.
I am not very experienced in ActionScript, but I can do basic things like set positions of objects.
I do not know how to retrieve information from a database via Flash.
I do not know how to make Flash send out queries.

Do you think you could give me a bit of help?

Comment: You will not get any concrete answers if you can't present any code, possible API, example data or a supposed table structure.

Comment: What does "safe" mean in this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be safe to use MySQL.
But, I strongly wouldn't recommend using PHP + MySQL as a game server though, or your server will tend to lock up from the influx of requests. The HTTP protocol was not designed for this.

It might take a bit of time, but I would learn an easy programming language (especially something like Java or C#) to create a basic server. Then you can store their user information within RAM, instead of constantly accessing the database repeatedly. But, you could also have it where the server updates a database every n amount of minutes, in case the server is shutdown and needs to be started back up with the same data.

Comment: Agreed. And using PHP+MySQL in this way has performance disaster written all over it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm very good at learning languages. I'll see what I can do with Java!

Answer (score 1):

Look up 'Flash Remoting' for flash<->server communications. An open-source server-side handler for that is [AMFPHP](http://amfphp.org). Flash would send out AMF messages, AMFPHP translates that back into normal PHP data structures, and then you'd have the PHP code handle interfacing to the database.

Answer (score 0):

you would have php be a controller between your db and flash.  So flash would send/receive info from php and php would query db.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, MySQL is pretty secure, as long as you strip all tags, mysql injection etc from the string. And it should be pretty instant.

However, hundreds of MySQL requests every second will be a lot of bandwidth, although I can't think of any alternatives.

Comment: Just realised this answer mainly focused on security, not on the actual technicalities of the task. Sorry!